# How to configure Gmail API for node.js?

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I did all steps described in [this doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs#step_3_set_up_the_sample).
But when I execute:

`node quickstart.js`

I get response:

> {[Error: invalid_grant] code: 400 }

My code:

```
fs.readFile('../../config/gmail-auth-key.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
 var count = 0;

if (err) {
   console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
   return;
}
// Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
// Gmail API.
authorize(JSON.parse(content), sendMessage);

function sendMessage(auth) {

  gmail.users.messages.list({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me'
  });
 }
});
```

I used Gmail API previously and maybe some token file was generated in the system?

Comment: Error 400 is a bad request. Did you manage to get the original quickstart sample working? 

The quickstart sample says that:

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/gmail-nodejs-quickstart.json

Since you've used Gmail API before (given you didnt encounter any errors), try going to that location and delete your previously saved credentials.

Comment: @noogui, thank you a lot, it has helped.
I looked for this file but without results

Comment: Where you have `userId: 'me'` try replacing `'me'` with your gmail address. Like `'arsenowitch@gmail.com'`.